# Passing Object with ModelAndView then parsing with JSTL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

This seems like it should work, but I just can't seem to figure out why, hoping a fresh set of eyes can spot what must be something very obvious...

I pass an object from my controller to my jsp file, but trying to parse the object with EL just will not work, it works as a scriptlet though, its driving me crazy :)

Using Spring 3.0 MVC

Model:

```
public class Table {

private String mId;
private ArrayList<Row> mRows;

public String getId() {
    return mId;
}
```

Controller:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.setId("test");

ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.addObject("table",table);
mav.setViewName("report");

return mav;
```

JSP File:

```
<!--  this works -->

<%
Table table = (Table)request.getAttribute("table");
System.out.println(table.getId());
%>

<!--  this does not work -->

${table.getId}
```

Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/report.jsp at line 33

30: 
31:     <!--  this dows not work -->
32: 
33:     ${table.getId}
34: 
35: </body>
36: </html>

javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getId' not found on type com.platform.server.portal.model.Table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `private String mId;` to `private String id;` 
and 
`${table.getId}` to `${table.id}`

you do not need to and can not  use accessor method like that.

if it must be mId then change

`public String getId()`to `public String getMid()`

and

`${table.getId}` to `${table.mId}`

Comment: The funny thing is that if @Telegard had done a ${table} whould have seen something fishy :P\